# alfresco strange fields in database (alf_node_properties)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, alfresco

I have strange fields in alfresco database (mysql), tables alf_node_properties (serializable_value) and act_ge_bytearray (BYTES_)

in ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY (BYTES_) type longblob

```
 �� sr $org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName71378920 IhashCodeL       localNamet   Ljava/lang/String;L 
inviteOutcomet ;http://www.alfresco.org/model/workflow/invite/nominated/1.0p   |                               namespaceURIq ~ L prefixq ~ xp    t
```

in HEX format:

```
 ACED0005737200246F72672E616C66726573636F2E736572766963652E6E616D6573706163652E514E616D65373133373839323002000449000868617368436F64654C00096C6F63616C4E616D657400124C6A6176612F6C616E672F537472696E673B4C000C6E616D65737061636555524971007E00014C000670726566697871007E000178700000000074000D696E766974654F7574636F6D6574003B687474703A2F2F7777772E616C66726573636F2E6F72672F6D6F64656C2F776F726B666C6F772F696E766974652F6E6F6D696E617465642F312E3070
```

in alf_node_properties (serializable_value) type blob

```
 ��~r,org.alfresco.service.cmr.version.VersionTypexrjava.lang.EnumxptMAJOR
```

I saw this when i do a migration to postgresql and i encounter this error:

```
 ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

It's safe to delete this entries, almost 700000?
I think the problems apears at first utf8 characters ( ��~r ).

I'll try to delete this values and then to test my alfresco in postgresql with value.

Thank you,
Geo

Comment: Have you perhaps had one of your mysql database or your Alfresco database connection URL not correctly configured for unicode / utf-8?

Comment: i have `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in **server.xml** and **mysql** have default `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: What about the jdbc connection string? And have those always been correctly set?

Comment: i think i changed `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` after one mounth of alfresco server.

Comment: That means you'll have 1 month of data that isn't utf-8, which would explain why your database contains a mixture...

Comment: thanks, i deleted all garbage and migration to postgresql was ok. Right now there's no errors in alfresco.